# magento admin button Interner Server error 500

Tags: magento, button, admin, panel, internal

my problem ist that: I have add a button in product edit page in admin panel, after clicking it, a csv file will be generated with all the product information per storeview.
When I tested it local, it works, but lasts more or less 7-8 minutes, but when i put in the live server, it stops at about 2-3 minutes, and shows the information "Interner Server Fehler(error) 500".
What could be this problem? After searching the solution from the internet, most said that changing the index.php permission, change the unlimited memory in .htaccess or php.ini, but i tried all, not worked.
I hope anybody has met the same problem before und solved to give me some suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest increase time limit on php.ini and httpd.conf

Refer this link - http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts

I'm not sure the error code is not timeout.
hope to solve that good luck!